# `kableExtra::kbl()` digits is ignored

Tags: r, kableextra

When specifying four digits to `kableExtra::kbl()`, they are ignored.

Consider

```
set.seed(423423)
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1))

print(dat, digits = 10)
#>                 y
#> 1  -0.19283314742
#> 2  -0.02577895889
#> 3   0.40861185274
#> 4   4.02791235921
#> 5   0.07579388805
#> 6  -2.12905634675
#> 7   0.13334935904
#> 8  -0.47837133966
#> 9  -1.08703811240
#> 10  0.06579553751
```

Created on 2023-01-27 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

```
kableExtra::kbl(dat, digits = 4)
```

[![kbl][1]][1]

What's going on?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AZeb.png

Answer (score 0):

The trick lies with the `getOptions(digit)`.

**The global `digit` must be greater or equal to the `digit` specified in `kbl`.**

From the example above

```
getOption("digits")
# [1] 2
```

which is less than the number of digits I want `4` so the kbl returned consists of `2` dps.

So resetting the global digits to `10` does the trick:

```
options(digits = 10)
set.seed(423423)
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1))

dat
#>                 y
#> 1  -0.19283314742
#> 2  -0.02577895889
#> 3   0.40861185274
#> 4   4.02791235921
#> 5   0.07579388805
#> 6  -2.12905634675
#> 7   0.13334935904
#> 8  -0.47837133966
#> 9  -1.08703811240
#> 10  0.06579553751

kableExtra::kbl(dat, digits = 4)
```

[image: kbl-1]